# Does the iPad browser support jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ipad, safari

Does anyone know of any limitations with the iPad version of Safari and jQuery libraries?

I know there are issues with Flash, but are there any other gotchas that I should be wary of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes .. the iPad supports jQuery just fine.

There's even a whole set of plugins specifically for the iPad.
http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/ipad

Answer (score 4):

The iPad supports a Safari-flavored Javascript implementation, so yes, jQuery works fine. The only limitation is that the iPad's CPU is a bit less powerful than your average computer's, so if you do CPU-intensive things like animations or large data set sorts, it might be somewhat slow/sluggish.

Answer (score 1):

generally if you use jquery rollovers and clicks events, on a ipad this becomes an annoying 2 stage click. One for the rollover and one for the click.